# how can we reduce the .xcframwork file size generated from the KMM library?

Tags: ios, kotlin-multiplatform, xcframework

I am creating a KMM library for my existing iOS and Android apps, I wanted to know about all the factors that I should consider while building the library that can affect the size of the `.xcframework` file.

Comment: The size of the xcframework is not the size that your app will be, if that's your concern. To reduce the size impact of your Kotlin library on the final app size, the only advice I can give without knowing what you're doing is to reduce how much code is publicly exported. Make as much code as you can internal. Minimize explicit exports, and definitely avoid exporting transitive.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. Just one thing, I didn't get the transitive part.

Comment: You can tell Kotlin to transitively export libraries to the framework, but it's generally a bad idea. See transitiveExport. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-cocoapods.html#add-and-configure-kotlin-cocoapods-gradle-plugin